# Change the text size of string on tabhost

Tags: android, android-tabhost, text-size

I want to change the text size of uyari_str but I couldn't. My code is:

```
tabHost.addTab(spec);     
    view = new MyView(this, R.drawable.res_tab_uyar);

    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("uyar").setIndicator(buildIndicator(R.string.uyari_str)).setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory(){

        @Override
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            return tv;
        }       
    });
```

Comment: have u try is using Html.fromHtml ?

Comment: have u tried it because we also embed html <b></b> in strings.xml file

Comment: how can I change? 

my strings is:

<string name="uyari_str">Warnings</string>

Comment: try as buildIndicator(Html.fromHtml("<b>"+R.string.uyari_str+"</b>")

Comment: not working. Sting is not shown on the screen

Answer (score 0):

For example, your tabhost including 4 items in a relative layout.

After all, you can use `getTabWidget().getTabCount()` to get tab count..

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rl.getChildAt(1);

    textView.setTextSize(15); // for example.
    }
```

You can use this code or something like this. :)

Best regards.